# How can I remove this ceiling light glass?

Tags: lighting

I cannot manage to get this light off. I've tried twisting, pushing, pulling, and a combination of those and nothing has worked. It moves about a centimeter in each direction but won't loosen any further.

Any suggestions?

[image: light light][image: view of light using a mirror]

Comment: Some light globes screw on and some actually are spring loaded if their are no screws, so you can try pulling firmly down or rotating the globe CCW. Those are the 3 main methods. With the thumb screw answer below.

Comment: With a hammer. Then get an LED dome light.

Comment: Looks like hammer is the main option so far!

Comment: The added picture with the mirror really is not helping. If you do resort to a hammer make sure to be careful to trap all of the broken glass. One way to handle that is to take three plastic garbage bags and nest them inside one another. Then hold or secure it against the ceiling around the light fixture before whacking the glass. (Three layers to help prevent sharp shards from cutting all the way through the plastic bags).

Answer (score 4):

Hey all thanks for the help. Ended up using a hammer. This thing must have warped over time as it was just a twist off. It was very secure in there and wasn't budging. The movement I felt before was the actual mount. I put a nice new light on there and we are good to go!

Comment: I figured you were just rocking the housing around. Better to just break the lamp before you wreck the junction box.

Comment: Can you post pictures of the remnants?  Never seen a twist off before.

Answer (score 0):

It usually attaches via set of three thumb screws slightly below the rim of the glass.

Try looking and feeling around the edge.  Also beware  when removing it -- you can remove one screw, but you have to be careful on the second to avoid dropping it

Comment: Unfortunately there are no thumb screws.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will not immediately help you get the glass part off the light fixture but may guide toward an answer.

Place a mirror against the ceiling so that you can see over the rim of the glass part. Something like this would be useful:

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01IW1APTY)*</sup>

You could even consider getting someone to hold the mirror and then take a photo of the image in the mirror to post back here if there is a retainer detail that is not obvious to you.

Comment: Just looked with a mirror nothing, flush all the way around. Photo added to original.